# Vectorization MATLAB sum equation snippet

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am new to MATLAB, and would like to understand how we can vectorize below snippet, or how can i do it efficiently:

```
sum=0;
for i = 1:50
   sum=sum+i;
end
```

Comment: `sum` is also the name of an internal function of MATLAB. Try to avoid such variable names, as in your example you couldn't use the `sum` function after running this code (until `clear`ing the `sum` variable)

Comment: @hbaderts thanks for suggestion. i will avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum native function:

```
total = sum(1:50);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(1:50)
```

The above statement initializes a vector of length 50 starting from 1 to 50 (with increments of length 1), and then calls MATLAB's sum function on it, returning the sum of all elements in the vector.